# Google Admin SDK Push Notifications only sends sync message

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I am trying to set up the Push Notifications/Webhook for directory/user resources from the GSuite Admin API as described [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/push). When I create a new webhook, for user "update" events I immediately get a sync message but no messages for user updates. Are there specific types of user changes that cause an update message but not others?
The response from the API on hook creation is always 200 and the sync message all looks fine but no later messages arrive.

Comment: What update operations are you expecting to see in your logs? Can you provide any additional detail about your case?

Comment: As a test, I did the following 
1. created the webhook and received the sync message for the user update channel

2. I then edited the gender and the first name of my google account expecting to see an update message over the channel to my endpoint. 

My webhook service/address didn't receive any traffic from Google with an update event.

I thought maybe user updates only occur when certain fields change which could explain why no message is sent but didn't see anything in the docs detailing that.

Comment: At the moment, I'm just trying to inspect the update message to see what details are included in the event payload so the use case is pretty general.

Comment: We are facing similar problems. We have successfully for years used Admin SDK Directory API Users.watch. Recently the updates from G Suite have been stopped or decreased dramatically. We are monitoring hundreds of customer directories like this and there is certainly several update messages per minute in normal situation. Now there has been like 12 hour pauses and then some updates and then again hours of silence. The watch POST requests work well, but theres just no push notifications of User accounts arriving.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/watch

Answer (score 1):

#### This appears to be a bug!

There is already a report on Google's Issue Tracker which detail the same kind of behaviour:

- [Missing push notifications when successfully watching (subscribing) to Directory API events](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/162838980)

Google does seem to know about this issue - quoting from this bug report by a *"va...@google.com"*:

> I am filing this internally. And any updates will be posted here.

You can hit the ☆ next to the issue number in the top left on the aforementioned pages which lets Google know more people are encountering this and so it is more likely to be seen to faster.